# Views 3 "no results behavior" for different languages

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I use i18nviews for the translation and it works fine! Under the Point "no results behavior" can i only choose Global:Textarea, but this is not allowed in different languages.  What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug which is currently being worked on](http://drupal.org/node/1182210).

Comment: Super!!! Saw this link 1st time, thx!